# How to obtain the IP of iPhone app requests

Tags: network-protocols

Is it possible to obtain the IP, if so how, of requests made by an iPhone app.

I am trying to block requests from the app Tinder using IP blocking from a router, however I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

You must connect your iPhone to internet through a proxy like "Man-in-the-middle" (http://mitmproxy.org) to be able to sniff the connection and find the ports iPhone apps uses.

It is a little tricky, but it worth give a try.

Good luck!